# How to scroll to first child div, instead of all targeted child divs one-by-one-by-one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am targeting multiple similar child divs inside multiple container divs. Subsequently the page scrolls towards the first targeted child div.

Unfortunately, the page doesn't scroll towards the first child div and then stop scrolling. The page keeps scrolling towards all of the child divs one-by-one-by-one.

Without luck I am trying to change this behaviour. I wish the page would just stop scrolling at the first child div.

To see my problem in action please click on any year in the header: http://paintings.directory

Current jQuery code:

```
var $sections = $('section');
$('#index_year p, section p').on('click', function(e) {
  let year = $(this).data('y');
  $sections.each(function() {
    let $section = $(this);
    let $target = $('.' + year, $section);
    if ($target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 128
      }, 2000);
      $section.removeClass('yearNotFound');
      $section.animate({
        scrollLeft: $section.scrollLeft() + $target.position().left
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      $section.addClass('yearNotFound');
    };
  });
});
```

So far I have unsuccessfully tried to:

1. give the child divs I am targeting a class to then scroll to the first child div with that class as follows:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.class:visible:first').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

2. add `return, false;` after the current scrolling code as follows:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 128
}, 2000); return, false;
```

3. use a :first selector as follows:

```
$( "$target:first" )`
```

4. place the 'scrolling-code' outside of the loop, by making a separate

```
$('#index_year p, section p').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 128
    }, 2000);
});
```

5. add `scrollIntoView`, I just couldn't phantom where and how to use this.

So far it's not working out for me and I am therefor looking for help.

Comment: `$("$target")` - meant to be `$("#target")`?

Comment: You just need to exit the `.each()` loop as sso as there is a `$target.length`. So in that `if`, add a `return true;` at the end.

Comment: I see, where exactly do I place the return true? Behind `}, 2000);`?

Comment: Right before `} else {`... Inside the `if`. *(yes, I think we talk about the same place ;)* -- That is instead of `return, false;`. --  Replace that with `return true;` **no coma!**.

Comment: It's still scrolling through all of them http://paintings.directory I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi @JackBashford I believe there is no div with ID target, I think the $ instead of # has to do with `let $target = $('.' + year, $section);` please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In that case, do `$($target + ":first")`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette currently I have it like this with no luck: `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 128 }, 2000); return true;`

Comment: Naa... Maybe I'm tired... Try `return false;` **but without coma**... Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop);

Comment: Same here, up for 40 hours, this did the trick, although now the rows without paintings from the targeted year are not fading out. Just some of them. I think we are now keeping all sections from temporary getting class yearNotFound.... (thanks for your time and effort!) http://www.paintings.directory

Comment: ;) Just before the `return false`, add `$(".yearNotFound").removeClass"yearNotFound");`. ;) -- Sleep is needed to keep a coder coding! Take care ;)

Comment: -_-" whoops and not all years scroll to the left so the scrollLeft bit also just works once. I see... return false stops the loop, therefore stops all the scrolling down, however also keeps the original code from working correctly, should I just place the `$('html, body').animate({...});` section somewhere else completely? I have bitten of more than I can chew that's for sure.....

Comment: Ha ok... You want to add the class `yearNotFound` to all of them anyway (whern there's none)... I see... Hold on.

Comment: I would let the loop got through all... But instead of animating in that loop, I would store the first hit in another variable. After the loop, animate that one. So, `if($target.length && typeof($storedTarget) =="undefined")` --> store the target.

Comment: Wait that makes me think, if all the paintings I don't want to see have class `.yearNotFound` can I not then just scroll the `$('html, body)` towards the first div not having class `yearNotFound` something maybe like this: `first:div:NOT:.yearNotFound` or is this not possible? That has the same outcome? :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the first painting having the "year" class in another variable to procede to the scroll after the loop.

But the animation of each section having a matched date has to be in the loop...

```
$('#index_year p, section p').on('click', function(e) {
  let year = $(this).data('y');
  var $storedTarget;

  $sections.each(function() {
    let $section = $(this);
    let $target = $('.' + year, $section);
    if ($target.length) {

      // Store the target here.
      if(typeof($storedTarget) == "undefined"){
        $storedTarget = $target.first();  // The first one!
      }

      // Animate sections left/right if there's a match
      $section.animate({
        scrollLeft: $section.scrollLeft() + $target.position().left
      }, 1500);

      $section.removeClass('yearNotFound');
    } else {
      $section.addClass('yearNotFound');
    }
  });

  // Make sure there is at least a result..
  if($storedTarget.length>0){

    // Scrolling to the first section that has a match
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $storedTarget.offset().top - 128
    }, 1500);

  }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191201/discussion-on-answer-by-louys-patrice-bessette-how-to-scroll-to-first-child-div).

Comment: Let us continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191201/discussion-on-answer-by-louys-patrice-bessette-how-to-scroll-to-first-child-div)

Comment: Beautiful solution. Works like a charm. Thank you @LouysPatriceBessette